# Running rsync as root: Operations Not Permitted

Tags: macos, bash, scripting, permissions, backup

World!

I have a backup script that would run `rsync` for every user and will archive their `/User/user` folder onto our shared drive. Running into an interesting problem with `rsync`: when executing the script as "sudo" from the shell as the current user I'm unable to preserve the permissions of other users. It will error out and say: `rsync: chown <path> - operations not permitted(1)`

Do I have to `chown` every user's folder as root before executing the command?
The command in being used and in question:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -av --human-readable --progress /Users/$name/ --exclude=".*" --exclude="Public" /Backup/$name\ -\ $(date +%m-%d-%y)  --exclude=".*/"
```

Thank you!

Comment: "Do I have to chown every user's folder as root" Hey, don't do that, your users will kill you.

Comment: @4ae1e1 You have a good point there...

Comment: What exactly is this "shared drive"? What happens if you try to `sudo chown` a file on it "by hand"?

Comment: @Gordon Shared drive as in our mounted network volume drive. It's where we archive and backup our data to.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's because the target is on a mounted network volume. You're running `rsync` as root, but that only gives you permissions to change ownership on the local (client) computer -- as far as the file server is concerned, you're whatever user authenticated to it, i.e. not root (unless you're using NFS, in which case it's more complicated). Since you're authenticated to the server as a normal user, all files you create on the server will be owned by that normal user, and you won't have permissions to change that.

I see two possible solutions:

- Don't try to set ownership on the server. Use `rsync -rltgoDv ...` instead of `rsync -av ...`. `-a` is equivalent to `-rlptgoD`; leaving off the `-p` means it won't try to set ownership on the target files, it'll just store them all as the current (authenticated to server) user.
- If you really need to preserve ownership (and your local accounts are the same as those on the server), run rsync over SSH instead of file sharing, and SSH into the server as root. Something like `rsync -av ... root@server:/Backup/$name\ -\ $(date +%m-%d-%y) ...`

  Note that allowing root SSH into a server is generally a bad idea. If you want to do it this way, I'd create an SSH public/private key pair (with an encrypted private key), use that for authentication, and configure the server to reject password-based SSH authentication (at least for root).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your quick response. It's probably best I use the correct `rysnc` arguments and flags to store the files as the current user and you did exactly that.

Comment: Brilliant and profound answer, thank you Gordon! Rsync over SSh was an easy fix. I performed a "local" rsync over AFP first and then a complementary rsync over SSH for the missing files which only took a short while.

Comment: According to the `man`, you should also be able to do `-av --no-perms`.

Comment: As @Zubo suggested and also per the `man` pages, it seems preferable to use the `-a` flag and specify which options to leave out, rather than translate the `-a` flag to those options. So in this case, you could use `rsync -avh --no-perms --no-group --no-owner`. This way you also wouldn't need to run `rsync` as `root`.

Comment: is there any way of doing this with docker, since I am storing my data on remote drive.

Comment: @Aqua4 I'm not particularly familiar with Docker, but I don't know of a reason it'd be very different from a physical machine.